# Filter Firestore Collection by Document Reference-Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

How does one filter a Firestore collection by a document reference in the web console? For example, I have a collection that references another collection document called `challenges`.
[image: Data Structure]

But no matter what combination I use to try to filter that collection by the `challenge ID` it returns no results. I need to be able to do this so I can look at all of the documents in this collection that reference back to that particular challenge reference.

[image: Filtering]

I am assuming this is possible in the console, but maybe it is not?

Comment: That is not support as far as I know. Nice feature request though.,

Comment: I submitted a feature request. Seems like an obvious add to me.